# Как сделать что бы при нажатии на кнопку в телеграмм боте отправлялся стикер?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, button

Пробовал много вариантов этот 1 который не выдаёт ошибку а просто нечего не отправляет(
`if message.text == 'текст': bot.send_sticker = open('static/sauf.`

Answer (score 0):

```
sti = open('static/sauf.webp', 'rb')
bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)
```

Ваш код само собой ничего не отправляет, потому что вы вместо того, чтобы отправить открытый файл в метод send_stiker, просто сносите напрочь этот метод и вместо него помещаете файл.